# how to search location by place name in elasticsearch like "location" : "India"

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to filter twitter data by location.I've used the query below ...

code :

```
query = { 
    "query": {
        "term" : { 
            "location" : "India"
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not getting desired output

Comment: what output do you get?

Comment: what is your mapping for field location?

Comment: {u'_shards': {u'failed': 0, u'successful': 5, u'total': 5},
 u'hits': {u'hits': [], u'max_score': None, u'total': 0},
 u'timed_out': False,
 u'took': 1}